# missing URL characters in SSRS Go to URL

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I have defined an Action on my Textbox to Go to an URL. For that I have used Go to URL in Action. URL is coming from a field value in my database. Below is my code in the Expr.

`"javascript:void(window.open('"+Field!urlfield.Value+"'))"`

My URLs sometimes have %5c, %20, %40 in them, when i used Go to URL action with Javascript,the URLs are missing these characters so the link does not open. When i use it without Javascript, URL opens but in the same page as the report. Users want the report to be opened in new tab/window.

I tried Encoding/Decoding URL by adding system.web reference to my report to use function encodeuri & decodeuri as described in the link http://capstonebi.blogspot.com/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html

```
Public Function URLEncode (ByVal inURL As String) As String
  Dim outURL As String
  outURL = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inURL).ToString
  Return outURL
End Function

Function Decode(ByVal EncodedString AS String) AS String
  Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(EncodedString)
End Function
```

I expected the link will be decoded and then passing it to encoding string as input to Javascript.void.window will resolve missing characters but it is still the same.

Question:
1. Is there any other way to open the link in new window (Other than ctrl+click).
2. If not, how can i resolve missing the URL characters.

Comment: Use a hyperlink instead of JS? Or use the second argument to `window.open()` to specify where it should open?

Comment: We have different URLs for each row, using just Field!urlfield.Value is opening the link in the same window as the report, Requirement is to open the link in new tab/window. with _blank or not the URLs are getting modified.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. SSRS is just asp, so can't you do `'<a href="' +Field!urlfield.Value+'" target="_blank">Link</a>'` or `"javascript:void(window.open('"+Field!urlfield.Value+"', '_blank'))"` ?

Comment: Lets say my link is one of the URL "http://<Servername>/opendoc.htm?document=abc%5Cmyreport%20name.extension&host=XXX%40servername". From the report with Javascripting the link is opening as http://<Servername>/opendoc.htm?document=abcmyreport name.extension&host=XXX@servername

Comment: No idea. Either `Field!urlfield.Value` is wrong or you might have to properly escape certain characters to make the JS work. I was hoping adding _blank in the correct place would already fix the issue since I can't help with the encoding.